# Prove (or disprove) that these numbers are Liouville numbers

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, liouville-numbers

How would I prove (or disprove) that these following numbers are Liouville:

$\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{\left(n!\right)!}$

$\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(n!\right)^{-n!}$

Both of these numbers seem to have continued fractions that have mirroring* terms and terms that grow larger and larger very rapidly, without bound.

And I'm stuck. I know what makes a Liouville number what it is, but still, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in these cases you should work in this way:
$$A_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$$
Since $a_n\to 0$ very fast and $A_n$ is a rational number you may hope that $\forall n$ large enough
$$\forall c>0,\ \ \sum_{i=n}^\infty a_i<(den(A_n))^{-c}$$
For example, in the first case $$den(A_n)=(n!)!$$ while for $n$ large enough
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty a_i<\frac{2}{((n+1)!)!}$$
since 
$$\frac{2(n!)!^c}{((n+1)!)!}\to 0$$
for all $c$ you have done